# How to end a sentence (if at all) with a preposition?

Tags: prepositions

My first quarter of school included classes such as *Biology*, *Chemistry*, and *Algebra*, all of which I received an A in.

I am confused because i thought you shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition. This is for a very formal letter so proper grammar is very important.

If not, how can i rework this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It is not always wrong to end a clause with a preposition, but, in some cases, it is considered incorrect. Here are cases of correct placement at the end.

- John was left with no one to talk to.
- (ref.: CGEL) I bought a car for Mary to drive to work in.
- ([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=L6aBecZEhDsC&pg=PT32&dq=%22punishing+him+for+?%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy-IGOwePtAhXqAWMBHa5LB8kQ6AEwInoECFEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22punishing%20him%20for%20%3F%22&f=false)) And if Job did feel this, what did he imagine God was punishing him for?

However, in your sentence the preposition can't be placed at the end; this is felt to be an awkward construction. They are several ways to make that right; here are two.

- My first quarter of school included classes such as Biology, Chemistry, and Algebra, in all of which I received an A.
- My first quarter of school included classes such as Biology, Chemistry, and Algebra; in all of those, I received an A.

Comment: thank you so much! just a general question, what do you mean by "awkward construction?" is this a grammatical error or is this a subjective thing?

Comment: @user130306 It's subjective, it results from my reader's experience; I never would choose that possibility, it just feels awkward to me.